# Server 2012 Can't Open Any File Shares

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-sharing, azure

I have two VM's of Server 2012 on Azure. From A I can access B via \\10.4.2.6\c$ without issue. Until yesterday I can access B from A via \\10.4.2.4\c$. I can still ping B from A and get a response. Disabling both firewalls doesn't help.

The error message I get *immediately* upon doing a Run command to \\10.4.2.4\c$ is `Windows cannot access \\10.4.2.4\c$`. I read that there are some KB articles that talk about something like this, but I've installed everything from Windows Update and rebooted several times and I still have the same issue.

I should add that this is an image provided by MS as part of Azure. I haven't changed it at all since I was last using it. I connected to server B from server A, copied some files, and shut the VM down. This morning I turned it on and tried to copy some other files and couldn't. Further testing revealed that I can't connect to any share anywhere in the company and I used to have no issues. The error is always the same and always immediate.

I can not connect to any shares whatsoever on any system with in the network from that machine. I can connect to said shares from other machines on the same subnet. I can ping the machines I can't connect to with no issue. I was able to connect to several shares just the day before.

Browsing to \\10.4.2.4\ yields the same error. Network sharing is enabled; I disabled and re-enabled it to be sure. I shared C:\Temp on 10.4.2.4 and SoftPerfect Network Scanner sees 10.4.2.4, but no shares. I can RDP to 10.4.2.4 with no issue.

Comment: Maybe administrative shares are disabled. You could try to explicitely define your own shares, something like `\\10.4.2.6\driveC`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: "Further testing revealed that I can't connect to any share anywhere in the company and I used to have no issues"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working now.
https://superuser.com/questions/575758/win7-share-cannot-access-localhost-and-cannot-share-folder

I removed all the “hidden” network adapters in device manager, rebooted, and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I would try maybe just sharing out a specific folder on the C: drive and seeing if that works and for testing give everyone full control. If that doesn't work I would give specific permissions to the C Drive as to what gets shared out.

Comment: I can view any shared and files on the troubled server that I want from any other location. I can't see any files or shares residing elsewhere from the troubled server.

Comment: I know this may sound silly but have you tried just typing in \\10.4.2.4\ and seeing if anything comes up that way. If that doesn't work I Know in WIndows 7/8/8.1 you have to enable networking and sharing for you to be able so see other people on the network. The other option would be if the drive is shared out I would run soft perfect net scanner and scan the range of your network and see if you can double click and browse it. Lastly I would try to map the drive with that path.

Comment: \\10.4.2.4\ yields the same error. Network sharing is enabled; I disabled and re-enabled it to be sure. I shared C:\Temp on 10.4.2.4 and SoftPerfect Network Scanner sees 10.4.2.4, but no shared. I can RDP to 10.4.2.4 with no issue.

Comment: I really cant think of anything else other than something is corrupted with the image you have.Or out of curiosity did you try changing the IP of the box that is not working to a different one to see if that would fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You can opened the following ports on windows firewall, advanced setting , inbound rules then create a new rule:
TCP 137 -139 ,445

UDP 137 -139 ,445

This helped in my case. 
Thanks

Comment: Please read the OP's question carefully. Was your problem identical to the one of the OP? If it's the same, why does the solution differ? If it's **not** the same, please consider posting **another** question.